# How to replace those entries in a column which have parenthesis or numbers included with them in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
I have a dataframe like this:         
    Country                  Energy Supply      Energy Supply per Capita
16  Afghanistan              3.210000e+08       10.0    
17  Albania                  1.020000e+08       35.0    
18  Algeria                  1.959000e+09       51.0    
19  American Samoa           NaN                                        
40  Bolivia 
   (Plurinational State of)  3.360000e+08       32.0
... ... ... ...
213 Switzerland17            1.113000e+09       136.0   
214 Syrian Arab Republic     5.420000e+08       28.0    
215 Tajikistan               1.060000e+08       13.0    
216 Thailand                 5.336000e+09       79.0    
228 Ukraine18                4.844000e+09       107.0   
232 United States of 
    America20                9.083800e+10       286.0
```

I needed to replace name of all those countries which are having parenthesis or numbers in their name. For example: 'Bolivia (Plurinational State of)' should be 'Bolivia','Switzerland17' should be 'Switzerland' and 'United States of America20' should be 'United States of America'.
I tried this using replace() and split() but nothing worked out for me.

Can somebody please help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex pattern with `str.extract`:

```
df['Country'] = df.Country.str.extract('^([^\d\(]*)')[0]
```

Output:

```
                      Country  Energy Supply  Energy Supply per Capita
16                Afghanistan   3.210000e+08                      10.0
17                    Albania   1.020000e+08                      35.0
18                    Algeria   1.959000e+09                      51.0
19             American Samoa            NaN                       NaN
40                   Bolivia    3.360000e+08                      32.0
213               Switzerland   1.113000e+09                     136.0
214      Syrian Arab Republic   5.420000e+08                      28.0
215                Tajikistan   1.060000e+08                      13.0
216                  Thailand   5.336000e+09                      79.0
228                   Ukraine   4.844000e+09                     107.0
232  United States of America   9.083800e+10                     286.0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use multiple `regex` with **[`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html)** like this:

Consider below dataframe:

```
In [1431]: df 
Out[1431]: 
                            Country
0                       Afghanistan
1  Bolivia (Plurinational State of)
2                     Switzerland17

In [1433]: df['Country'] = df['Country'].str.replace(r"\(.*\)|\d+",'')
In [1434]: df  
Out[1434]: 
         Country
0    Afghanistan
1       Bolivia 
2    Switzerland
```

Comment: `.str.replace(r"\(.*\)|\d+",'')` to avoid calling two times.

Comment: @Ch3steR Thanks a lot. Edited my answer.

Comment: Fantastic! This has worked for me. Thanks a lot @Mayank Porwal Could you just tell me the logic behind the regex expression you have used, I'm unable to understand that?

Comment: @AniruddhMaini Logic is : there are 2 regex, separated by `pipe(|)`. First is to identify parantheses`()` and remove it with all text within it. Second one is to simply remove `any numbers` from the text.

Answer (score 1):

```
df.Country = df.Country.str.extract(r"([^(\d]+)")
```

> ```
>       Country              Energy Supply     Energy Supply per Capita
> 16   Afghanistan           3.210000e+08     10.0
> 17   Albania               1.020000e+08     35.0
> 18   Algeria               1.959000e+09     51.0
> 19   American Samoa                 NaN     NaN
> 40   Bolivia               3.360000e+08     32.0
> 213  Switzerland           1.113000e+09     136.0
> 214  Syrian Arab Republic  5.420000e+08     28.0
> 215  Tajikistan            1.060000e+08     13.0
> 216  Thailand              5.336000e+09     79.0
> 228  Ukraine               4.844000e+09     107.0
> ```