# How do I remove () or numbers from a database record using python

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

There are also several countries with numbers and/or parenthesis in their name. Be sure to remove these,

e.g.

'Bolivia (Plurinational State of)' should be 'Bolivia',

'Switzerland17' should be 'Switzerland'.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to replace those entries in a column which have parenthesis or numbers included with them in a pandas dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62158951/how-to-replace-those-entries-in-a-column-which-have-parenthesis-or-numbers-inclu)

Answer (score 0):

IIUC `str.replace` with regex `\(.*\)|\d+`

```
s = pd.Series(['Bolivia (Plurinational State of)','Switzerland17'],name='Countries')
df = pd.DataFrame(s)
df['CountriesCleaned'] = df['Countries'].str.replace('\(.*\)|\d+','').str.strip()
```

---

```
print(df)

                          Countries CountriesCleaned
0  Bolivia (Plurinational State of)          Bolivia
1                     Switzerland17      Switzerland
```

---

Regex101 Explanation [here](https://regex101.com/r/xbU5J3/1)

Answer (score 0):

Data

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'text': ['Bolivia (Plurinational State of)','Switzerland17']})
```

Use regex to extract the first word

```
 df['textextracted']=df.text.str.extract('(^[A-Za-z+]+)')



 text       textextracted
0   Bolivia      Bolivia
1   Switzerland  Switzerland
```